# Implement FileOutputStream like behaviour in Spring Rest JSON

Tags: java, json, outputstream, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to return a JSON to client on the request of a Question Number.
I am using Springs Rest Controller for this purpose; here is how the controller looks.

```
    package com.questions.controllers.rest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.questions.beans.QuestionBean;

@RestController
public class QuestionController {


    @RequestMapping("/question/{id}")
    public @ResponseBody QuestionBean loadQuestionByNumber(@PathVariable("id")int id){

        return new QuestionBean(id, "VeryLongQuestion");
    }
}
```

Issue: Instead of the String "VeryLongQuestion", I would like to send in a very long question, for example 1MB data , or more. Java's String might not support such big data.
How can I do it over here? I want to stream data. What should my QuestionBean contain?

Comment: The workaround I am thinking of is to get the really long description as a separate call for each question, sent as response. However, there must be a solution for sure